# splitting list of xts in separate objetcs

Tags: r, list, xts

Harnessing the  resources  posted on the forum, I managed to create a script that transforms files into objects of xts class. However, this is a list of those objects. Ultimately, I want to transform those files into separate objects xts. What I have to enter a change in the script that they appeared as separate objects, each of them  of xts class?

there is script :

```
files <- list.files( pattern="*.mst")
listmst <- vector("list", length(files))
names(listmst)<- files
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  temp <- read.zoo(files[i], sep=",", header=TRUE, 
                     index.column=1, format="%Y%m%d", tz="", 
                     colClasses = rep(c("NULL","character", "numeric"), c(1,1,5)))
  listmst[[files[i]]]<- as.xts(temp)
}
rm(temp,files)
```

csv files to tranform :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/paql3y0gm5gve3z/pourek.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like `assign` to create an object with the symbol name.  For example:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.mst")
for (f in files) {
  # Create symbol from file name
  Symbol <- gsub("\\.mst", "", basename(f))
  # Ensure it's a valid R name
  Symbol <- make.names(Symbol)
  # Read data from file
  temp <- read.zoo(f, sep=",", header=TRUE, format="%Y%m%d", tz="", 
                   colClasses = rep(c("NULL","character", "numeric"), c(1,1,5)))
  # Clean up column names
  colnames(temp) <- gsub("^X\\.|\\.$", "", colnames(temp))
  # Create object named `symbol` containing data from `temp`
  assign(Symbol, as.xts(temp))
}
rm(Symbol, temp, f)
```

Now you should see this in your workspace:

```
R> ls()
 [1] "ABPL"       "AILLERON"   "ALIOR"      "ALMA"       "ALTA"      
 [6] "ALTERCO"    "files"      "KREDYTIN"   "KREZUS"     "KRKA"      
[11] "KRUK"       "KRUSZWICA"  "MABION"     "MAKARONPL"  "MANGATA"   
[16] "MARVIPOL"   "MASTERPHA"  "MBANK"      "MBWS"       "MCI"       
[21] "MCLOGIC"    "MDIENERGIA" "MEDIACAP"   "MEDIATEL"   "X11BIT"    
[26] "X4FUNMEDIA"
R> head(ABPL)
            OPEN  HIGH   LOW CLOSE    VOL
2006-09-21 11.54 12.19 11.50 11.70 844641
2006-09-22 11.69 11.69 11.25 11.60  53033
2006-09-25 11.49 11.83 11.49 11.83 125607
2006-09-26 11.90 12.05 11.90 12.04 104956
2006-09-27 12.09 12.09 11.70 11.95  69062
2006-09-28 11.70 12.00 11.65 12.00  37466
```

Note that all the symbols that begin with a number now begin with an "X", because R objects that start with a number are not "syntactically valid".

Comment: This is exactly the result I was searching .Few days it takes before I fully understand the code. Thanks very much .